# Set Content Approval status using workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a Document Library with the following Settings: -

Require content approval for submitted items=  Yes
 Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited=No

I have a SPD approval workflow acting on a document library.  Everything works but I am now required that the user is forced to check-out the document.

I now set the document library to :

Require content approval for submitted items=  Yes
 Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited=Yes

The workflow fails due to requiring the document to be checked-out. So I add the following actions within the workflow

'Checkout item in current item' and 'Set Content Approval status to Approved' Actions in the workflow

Now workflow checks out document, but a different error occurs. workflow history shows :User Id System Account, Event type - Error

The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.

I've looked for soltions but cant find any answers. Any help appreciated, using 2010 with latest CU.

I've added actions to 'When a Task Completes'

[image]

Comment: i have same issue and looking for answer and/or work around

Comment: Did you manage to do it finally? what were the steps? Or did you hit Catch-22?

Answer (score 1):

If by "add Checkout" you mean that you added a new Outcome than you should know that is not a acceptable value for the Content Approval status which only accepts Approved, Rejected, or Pending.

Check-Out is an automatic state, but is unrelated to Approval of content.

Comment: I've updated my Original question to be more accurate. I dont maen a new Outcome. Any ieas ?

Comment: I suspect that the action "Set Content Approval" status already checks-in the document for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've been working on for several hours and finally got it.

The only way that I have found is to go into your settings for the folder, go to "versioning setting," and where it says "Require content approval for submitted items" select "no."

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to put the "change content approval status" step to AFTER the check-in, not while it's checked out.